# Is there a way figure out which resources in my web page aren't being served securely?

Tags: https

I just secured my web page with SSL, but the browser shows that not all of the resources are sent securely.

I tried:

- commenting out any third party APIs from my web page
- ensuring that all images are being served via the same server

it seems as if all of my content is being served from the same web host.

**Is there a way to figure out which resources in my web page aren't being served securely without going through the entire site and all content piece by piece?**

[image]

In my case, I'm securing a small page that I developed on my own, but in the future I might be asked to secure an entire site that I'm less familiar with, which could make going through every resource one-by-one impractical.

Comment: figured out that my problem was an image in the style sheet, but that's not necessarily the answer. I only found this after commenting all resources in my webpage out and putting them back one by one. In a page much bigger than mine, this seems impractical.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Firebug.

Open Firebug Click on the Console Tab and reload the page. Hover over each entry and the GET entry will display the URL it is retrieving.

Answer (score 0):

Chrome has the same functionality as Firebug only built in.   If you are using Chrome you can open:

1. Hamburger menu
2. More tools
3. Developer tools
4. Network

Then refresh the page and hover over each item to see if it is https or not.